# Does HTML5 permit encoding external scripts in UTF-16?

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, character-encoding, utf-16

The HTML standard requires¹ the use of the UTF-8 encoding for HTML documents.

Does it permit the use of other encodings for externally loaded scripts?

```html
<script src="/script1.js">
<script type="module" src="/script2.mjs">
```

These scripts would be encoded in UTF-16 rather than UTF-8 and would be served by the web server with the header `Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-16`. Does this setup comply with the HTML spec?

---

1. “The `charset` attribute [of a `meta` element] specifies the character encoding used by the document. This is a character encoding declaration. If the attribute is present, its value must be an ASCII case-insensitive match for the string "utf-8"” ([§ 4.2.5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-meta-element)). “Regardless of whether a character encoding declaration is present or not, the actual character encoding used to encode the document must be UTF-8” ([§ 4.2.5.4](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#charset)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like HTML5 [permits](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-a-classic-script) different encodings for regular scripts and [mandates](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-a-single-module-script) UTF-8 for JavaScript modules.

> To **fetch a classic script** given a *url*, a *settings object*, some *options*, a *CORS setting*, and a *character encoding*, run these steps. The algorithm will asynchronously complete with either null (on failure) or a new classic script (on success).
>
> [...]
>
> 7. If *response*'s Content Type metadata, if any, specifies a character encoding, and the user agent supports that encoding, then set *character encoding* to that encoding (ignoring the passed-in value).
> 8. Let *source text* be the result of decoding *response*'s body to Unicode, using *character encoding* as the fallback encoding.
>
> [...]

> To **fetch a single module script**, given a *url*, a *fetch client settings object*, a *destination*, some *options*, a *module map settings object*, a *referrer*, and a *top-level module fetch* flag, run these steps. The algorithm will asynchronously complete with either null (on failure) or a module script (on success).
>
> [...]
>
> 10. Let *source text* be the result of UTF-8 decoding *response*'s body.
>
> [...]

Answer (score 1):

> The HTML standard requires the use of the UTF-8 encoding for HTML documents

No, it doesn't. It *prefers* UTF-8, but you can use any other charset you want, as long as you declare it explicitly in an appropriate `<meta>` element.  See [Declaring character encodings in HTML](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations).

> Does it permit the use of other encodings for externally loaded scripts?

The `<script>` element has a [`charset` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/semantics-scripting.html#element-attrdef-script-charset), though this is deprecated in favor of the `charset` attribute of the `Content-Type` HTTP header when the script is retrieved.  If `charset` is present in the `<script>`, it must match the `charset` of the `Content-Type`.  If no `charset` is specified, the HTML's charset is assumed.

Comment: I added a couple of citations confirming that HTML5 mandates UTF-8 for new documents.

Comment: @TillUlen while UTF-8 is the preferred and only "conformant" charset in the modern "Living Standard" (the previous HTML5 and earlier standards have no such restriction), the wording of [this FAQ](https://github.com/whatwg/html/blob/main/FAQ.md#how-do-i-specify-the-character-encoding) in the latest standard doesn't dismiss the possibility of other charsets being used: "*The character encoding name given must be the name of the character encoding used to serialize the file.*" Of course, do use UTF-8 if possible and feisible to do so, but do know that browsers are typically backwards compatible.